# Json or XML, what to use as backend datastore for a quiz app?

Tags: xml, json

I am creating a quiz application. Different Questions might have different number of choices. For the backend datastore, where the questions and answers would be stored, i want to use either JSON or XML .

if i use XML, i could do something like :

```
<Parent>
<Question> what? </Question>
<choice> nothing </choice>
<choice> is a four letter word </choice>
<choice> ?thaw </choice>
</Parent>
```

(seems structured and comfortably readable)

while if i try to achieve similar structure with JSON, i will probably have to create an array of choices like :

```
"choices" : {"nothing","is a four letter word","?thaw"}
```

(in this case, the readability is compromised)

or i could dynamically create choices as different property names.

```
"choice1": "nothing",
"choice2": "is a four letter word",
"choice3": "?thaw"
```

(not a good structure for parsing)

Am I missing something here ? 
I believe i have encountered many arguments in favor of JSON over XML, that say JSON is more readable and structured. (Json is less verbose and  faster that is for sure)

Comment: you don't need readability in json text, because json text is meant to be parsed by a json parser into an object. Objects are what you want. json is just a way to represent them.

Comment: @JonathanM wouldnt the same argument be valid for XML ?

Comment: Yes, equally valid. I was simply stating that you shouldn't be concerned with readability.

Comment: If you don't care about readability, for an application this simple either one is fine. As far as readability, imho XML is far more readable than JSON, except to someone who already knows Javascript but not anything XML-ish (like HTML). Kind of like the Latin alphabet is, imho, far more readable than Chinese orthography, except perhaps to someone who already knows Chinese but not anything Latin-ish (like English).